# How do I refresh a view (or a page) after a new comment has been posted?

Tags: views, rules, comments

I have a view that displays comments for a node. 
When user1 posts a new comment then that comment appears automatically in the view for user1. But for user2 viewing the same node, the new comment does not appear automatically without a page refresh (ie, the view does not get refreshed automatically).

I have tried to find an event in rules to trigger an event that could look like "refresh page" or "refresh view".

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Views Auto-Refresh](https://drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) module.

> A module to refresh a view after a specified time interval. Includes
>   advanced options to avoid reloading the whole view, and to avoid
>   causing a full Drupal bootstrap at each refresh.

If you are looking for REAL realtime update you should use some server side javascript like [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/), to push event to the dom.

also there is [nodejs](https://drupal.org/project/Nodejs) module for Drupal.

[A great tutorial](http://thereisamoduleforthat.com/content/auto-refreshing-views-real-time-information-streams)

Comment: I used the sandbox project [views nodejs](https://drupal.org/sandbox/AndrewsizZ/2046401) and it works very well.